# Which Comparator could match this electronic circuit?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, comparator

Below is a schematic of a current regulator using a comparator IC2.  The board is from an XP-605 ELENCO bench top adjustable power supply. Searching the WEB was unsuccessful in finding any original schematic so I resorted to reverse engineer the board and came out with this schematic. The configuration appear to be a simple negative feedback loop feeding a Darlington configuration for current amplification. IC2 is absent from the main electronic board. The PCB do not indicate which IC part number is utilized. It only shows a socket for a DIP8 chip. I found several possibilities of replacement comparators but none was using Pin7 as a power input and pin6 as the amplifier output. LM311 appear to be a potential candidate performance wise but not pin compatible with the DIP8 socket. From the schematic it would appear that pins 1,4,5 are utilized as a zero offset trimming capability.
[image]
So, my speculation suggest the following:
Pin1    Trim input
Pin2    negative input of a OpAmp or Comparator
Pin3    positive  input of a OpAmp or Comparator
Pin4    Negative supply
Pin5    Trim input
Pin6    Output (most probably open collector)
Pin7    Positive supply
Pin8    not used in the circuit, ?

[image]
[image]

The Question:  I am searching for a replacement IC  comparator ( perhaps OpAmp) to match the DIP8 pinout above described and compatible with the electronic schematic. Can anyone help ?
Much appreciation :)

Answer (score 1):

Further Datasheet research lead me to find that the popular 741 OpAmp was the replacement IC.